# how can i call an new activity from onPostExecute?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String myres = null;
        String bot_string = args[0] ;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("question", bot_string));


        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_pythonwebservice, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("results: ", json.toString());


        try {



            myres = json.getString(TAG_BOTRESPONSE);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return myres;



    }

 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();



        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),file_url , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        //Get reference to textview above in oncreate method
        //bot.setText(file_url);

    }


 if (file_url == "Navigation"){

            Intent i = new Intent(Voice.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

Toast is printing.I want to call `MapsActivity.class` if String `file_url == "Navigaion"` but this is not working if i put inside the `onPostExecute`. How can i call `MapsActivity.class`. This is a voice recognition application.

Comment: `if (file_url.equals("Navigation"))`

Comment: can you post the activity where you execute this AsyncTask?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/3830694

Comment: if (file_url.equals("Navigation") )
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(Voice.this, MapsActivity.class));
            } This is not working

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you should compare two string as,

```
if(string1.equals(string2))
 {
   // code block
 }
```

So, for your example, you should change your code like,

```
if (file_url.equals("Navigation"))
{
  // more code follows
}
```

Comment: if ("Navigation".equals(file_url) || "navigation".equals(file_url) )
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(Voice.this, MapsActivity.class));
            }                                                                                                                       I put this one but it did not work

Comment: Can you Log the file_url and show me the ouput. I believe you are getting some other value in file_url.